# Scrolling With Inner Scrollbar

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I have a website I'm scraping and need to scroll horizontal (to the far right) and vertical (to the very bottom) of a table that is on a webpage. I am using Python3, Selenium and Chrome Driver.

I can scrape the table data but it only scrapes as far down as what's visible on my webpage. When I inspect the webpage I cannot find any scrolling information.

Researching online I've seen various ways to scroll using Selenium even finding by xpath and then scrolling that way. I have not had luck with any option thus far but could be doing it wrong.

## This is an example of something I've tried but it does not work:

```
html=browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]')    
html.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

## This scrapes the rows without issue from the table (but only the ones visible on the webpage when the page is loaded. If I scroll all the way down, and rerun this code, it scrapes the contents of the entire table since it fully loads)

```
for tr in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]'):
        tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        action_log = ([tr.text for tr in tds])
```

I just want to be able to scroll vertically all the way to the bottom of the table and horizontally for as far as I can (just once after the page loads). Again, scrolling inside the table on the webpage - not in Chrome itself. As a note my table data size will change.

Comment: Could  you find any solution for this? I am also facing the same problem.. I already implemented similar to the solution also. But it is cannot acess element with sending of keys like page down, end or other

Comment: Hey @Priya, so my answer below is what I went with. #Click table in order to activate it in web browser to scroll down
    `browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]').click() 
#Scrolls To The Bottom Of The Action Log
    bg = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]')
    for _ in range(3):
        bg.send_keys(Keys.END)
        time.sleep(25)` If you have the site URL or some examples I would be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I kept combing the site to figure out how to scroll it and finally just ended up using this which worked wonderfully (since the site already has all the data pulled in). As a note, this is scrolling a table element that is at the bottom of the webpage not Chrome itself. Though it works best when the window is maximized.

```
bg = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[4]')
for _ in range(3):
        bg.send_keys(Keys.END)
        time.sleep(.5)
```